# SQL Empty parameter values

Tags: python, sql, python-3.x

I have a query which returns the sum of monthly sales of individual products in my database. The query works.

Instead of having a value for the "=?", is there an empty value to store in the "=?", without affecting the query. E.g., if I enter 'Espresso' for product, leave out milkOptions, and enter 'Small' for size, could I return the query result of all Small Espressos. I want this feature because I want for varying degrees of specificity

```
import sqlite3
product = input("Enter product")
milkOptions = input("Enter milkoptions")
size = input("Enter size")

conn=sqlite3.connect("system.db")
cur=conn.cursor()
test = cur.execute("""
select count(product), strftime("%m-%Y", orderDate) as month 
from customerOrders
where product = ? and milkOptions = ? and size = ? 
group by product, month""",(product, milkOptions, size)).fetchall()

+---------+---------------+--------+-------------+------------+
| orderid |    product    |  size  | milkOptions | orderDate  |
+---------+---------------+--------+-------------+------------+
|       1 | Espresso      | Small  | Soya        | 2019-10-29 |
|       2 | Cappucino     | Small  | SemiSkimmed | 2019-10-29 |
|       3 | Cappucino     | Small  | SemiSkimmed | 2019-10-29 |
|       4 | Cappucino     | Medium | SemiSkimmed | 2019-10-29 |
|       5 | Hot Chocolate | Medium | Coconut     | 2019-10-29 |
|       6 | Hot Chocolate | Medium | Coconut     | 2019-10-29 |
+---------+---------------+--------+-------------+------------+
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the columns don't have the NOT NULL constraint, you can assign their values to be NULL.

```
if milkOptions == "":
    milkOptions = "NULL"
```

Insert into the database after performing this statement. This is a rather inelegant workaround but it works.